# How to fix an illegal newline value when reading a csv file

Tags: python

I have had trouble reading a .csv file using Python 3.7. When I wrote:

```
import csv
with open ('iris.csv', newline =' ') as csv_file:
    rows = csv.reader(csv_file)
    for row in rows:
        print(row)
```

and ran the code, it just says:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-42d17202da4e> in <module>()
      1 import csv
----> 2 with open ('iris.csv', newline =' ') as csv_file:
      3     rows = csv.reader(csv_file)
      4     for row in rows:
      5         print(row)

ValueError: illegal newline value:
```

How can I fix this problem? And why is ' ' has an illegal value? I expcted it would be like:

```
['sepal_length', 'sepal_width', 'petal_length', 'petal_width', 'species']
['5.1', '3.5', '1.4', '0.2', 'setosa']
['4.9', '3', '1.4', '0.2', 'setosa']
['4.7', '3.2', '1.3', '0.2', 'setosa']
['4.6', '3.1', '1.5', '0.2', 'setosa']
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to use a space to separate lines?

Comment: How can lines in a CSV be separated by a single space?! What does your CSV look like?

Comment: Also, from the [`open` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open): *"[newline] can be `None`, `''`, `'\n'`, `'\r'`, and `'\r\n'`."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs : https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

> newline controls how universal newlines mode works (it only applies to text mode). It can be None, '', '\n', '\r', and '\r\n'.

In your case, `newline =' '` is invalid since it is not one of the characters listed in the values in the docs.

I think you got confused with a csv `delimiter` in [csv.reader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader), which is what separates two values in a csv file

> Dialect.delimiter
>   A one-character string used to separate fields. It defaults to ','.

Example

```
a,b,c,d
e,f,g,h
```

Based on what your delimiter is, you can specify that in the `delimiter` field while reading the csv

```
rows = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter="<your_delimiter>")
```